# How to Add image in pdf using C# and iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I need your help adding an image to a PDF.

I'm using:

```
string imgPath2 = localPath + "\\TempChartImages\\" + LegendPath;
img2.Save(imgPath2);
ith.WriteImage(imgPath2, 80);
```

But this code gives me the error:

> Use of  unassigned local variable img2

How can I solve this error?

Comment: I'm not sure what your code does (as its not very clear) but are you trying to add an image to a PDF? If so, use iTextSharp.

Comment: Can you post the code that defines img2?  You will need a library to do the insert in the PDF as there is nothing backed into the .NET framework to manipulate PDFs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the iTextSharp tutorial on [images](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch06.html).  Without seeing more of your code, it's tough to judge what piece of code from this you'll need.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable, in your case img2, without assigning a value it is pointing to absolutely nothing.  Make sure you initialize img2 to something before using it.

I think what you want your `img2.Save` line to be changed to:

```
Image img2 = Image.FromFile(yourInitialImageHere);  // You could be reading from memory as well.
img2.Save(imgPath2);
```

I could be way off though as your snippet of code is pretty vague.

Answer (score 2):

it's a hunch, but if you're assigning the value of `img2` inside a Try-Catch block you might be hitting an exception that prevents the assignment from taking place.  For example:

```
var img2;
try
{
    var x = 5 / 0; // Generate a DivideByZero exception
    img2 = GetImage(); // <-- the above exception will prevent this code from executing
}
catch
{
}
img2.Save(imgPath2); <-- img2 wasn't assigned, so another exception will occur
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some third-party tool for this.

Comment: It would be worth editing your question to include that information - probably even in the question header.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to instantiate first the Image.

```
Image img2 = new Image();
```

it solved my problems. Hope it will solve yours.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a getinstance of the image.

```
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("path of the image");
```